# Cloudant skip parameter not working

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to do paging of results from a Cloudant database.

I've tried using `bookmark`, but the fact that the final page of results still has a bookmark is a problem for me, since it means that apps using the database can't tell if there's a 'next page' or not without requesting it.

Instead, I've tried using `skip` with a URL like this:

```
https://samdutton.cloudant.com/mydb/_design/mydesigndoc/_search/mysearch?
q=foo:bar&skip=10
```

However, this isn't working: I always get the first page of results.

Am I doing something wrong, or should this work?

Comment: I don't see the `skip` param in the [docs](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#analyzers)

Comment: Take a look here: https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#get-documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping results isn't supported in search. [See the search documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#queries) for the full list of supported options.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to know a page is the last page of results, without requesting the next page?

Comment: I don't think there is